# Bitmap printing ESC/POS commands in 2021

Tags: bitmap, thermal-printer, escpos

The software i'm maintaining has been churning along printing bitmaps via [ESC *](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=88).
Recently i had to make some upgrades on another component and ended up using [GS v 0](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=94).

I find `ESC *` to be convoluted and hard to use, whereas `GS v 0` is considered obsolete. So the question is twofold:

- What is the recommended ESC/POS command to print bitmaps in 2021?
- What is *the most commonly supported* ESC/POS command in the wild?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EPSON document is as follows.
[Obsolete Commands - TM Printer ESC/POS Command](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=74#obsolete)

Both are described as being substitute by  command groups starting with GS(L/GS8L.
[GS ( L / GS 8 L - TM Printer ESC/POS Command](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=95)

---

However, some vendors other than EPSON and even EPSON may not support it depending on the printer model(For example, dot printer).
In such cases, `ESC *` is considered to be in active use.

Comment: Do you have timeframes for these commands? E.g., when did`GS v 0` become obsolete?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any information about it.